# Create User using Membership.CreateUser

Tags: asp.net

I used the following to create new users using SqlMembershipProvider. While trying to create new users using CreateUserWizard, it throws exception 'The username is already in use' even though there is no any user exists and also new row is creating successfully with this username and password in my table.

```
MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser(createWizard.UserName, createWizard.Password);
```

If i hard code the value of username and password no exception occurs.

Can any one tell me the reason why it throws the exception when using CreateWizard?

Answer (score 4):

```
MembershipCreateStatus status;
var user = Membership.CreateUser(login, password, email, null, null, true, out status);
```

Try this.

Comment: Passing null to question and answer when the  requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" in web.config throws error ".InvalidAnswer"

Answer (score 0):

Check in your Membership.dbo database if this user exists.

```
SELECT     *
FROM         aspnet_Users
WHERE     (UserName = 'YourUserName')
```

Comment: No I checked with that. I could not able to find the users. I could be able to find the exception even I don't have rows in my aspnet_Users table.

Comment: You checked and not exists in DB? This is really strange!!! Have you any created user in your system?

Comment: I see that in MembershipProvider this function pass more that two parameters - System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider public abstract MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status);

Comment: right. It is not needed to write 'MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser(createWizard.UserName, createWizard.Password);' if we using CreateUserWizard to create users for method CreateUser(username, password)

Comment: I never could use CreateUserWizard in the really world. Allways was some different point that I was need to change. Sorry. Check you config there are several parameters. Read more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295494(v=expression.40).aspx